# How can I change code based on Method Argument?

Tags: java, methods

```
public static void calculate(List<Person> data, String categoryType) {
       for(int i = 0; i < categoryData.size(); i++) {
            if(data.get(i).calculateCategoryOne() == firstPlace) { 
                 ...
            }
        }

}
```

If you see `data.get(i).calculateCategoryOne()`, the method call is for category one. The problem is that I need to copy-paste the entire code in a if-block for each category to just change this method call `data.get(i).calculateCategoryTwo()`, `data.get(i).calculateCategoryThree()`, ... `data.get(i).calculateCategoryTen()`,

While I can still make the logic work in this way, I feel it is redundant and not a good programming practice. Just to change one line of code, I would have to replicate the same code ten different times which will add nearly 500 lines of code.

So, my question is: Is there a way to dynamically change my method call based on the category type string argument.

I was thinking one possible way is to pass the method call in a string and convert it to a method call itself. For example, let's assume CategoryType string argument is `"calculateCategoryOne()"`. So, `data.get(i)."calculateCategoryOne()"` would be recognized by the compiler as the method call itself. Is there a way to actually implement this?

I'm open to other ideas as well to reduce redundancy.

Comment: You *could* use reflection, but probably don't. I'm not sure why you'd need to cut and paste the entire block of code if the only change is which method you call, which could be abstracted out into another method anyway, or moved to whatever `data.get(i)` returns, or...

Comment: What does your method `calculateCategoryOne()` do and what does it return? What is `firstPlace` and what has everything to do with the parameter `categoryType` , which you don't use at least in the snippet?  What do you want to achieve in general? Why does your class `Person` have ten different methods that do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I would think using a functional interface would be appropriate here. You want different functionality depending on the categoryType, so passing in the function you want to use, rather than a String representation of it, would accomplish this.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Calculate {
    int calculate(Person data);
}

public static void calculate(List<Person> data, Calculate calculate) {
       for(int i = 0; i < categoryData.size(); i++) {
            if(calculate.calculate(data.get(i)) == firstPlace) { 
                 ...
            }
        }
}
```

and the call to the method would define what the calculation would be

```
        calculate(list, p -> {
            // calculation done here
            
        });
```

or if this would happen frequently, you could predefine your categories once and pass those in:

```
Calculate categoryOne = p -> { ... };
Calculate categoryTwo = p -> { ... };
.
.
calculate(list, categoryOne);
```